# Сфера применения bootstrap

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend, bootstrap

У меня вопрос к людям, которые занимаются web-разработкой. Часто ли сейчас при создании сайтов на заказ используют bootstrap или его больше используют для админок, там где не нужно заморачиваться с интерфейсом? Используют ли его только для создания адаптивного каркаса сайта и т.д.? Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Используют везде. Например, мне больше нравиться изменить уже настроенный элемент под себя, чем настраивать с нуля.
 + удобно иметь один базис. И писать плагины, и использовать чужие.

Есть сервисов много для бутстрапа, что упрощают роботу:

- http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured
- https://wrapbootstrap.com/